# (iPhone and iPad) when clicking outside input field never loose´s focus - HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad

I have this Structure: 
`<div> 
<input type="text" name="completeName" id="completeName" value="" maxlength="50"> 
</div>`

When clicking outside this input field on iOS (Tablet or iPhone on Safari browser), I can´t loose focus and because of that the keyboard does not hide by itself.

How can I fix this issue ? (I tested it in Android environment and it works well)

Comment: Can you share the proper structure, not in some kind of abstracted code, but in real code? Probably, a reduction to a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps

Comment: Hi @JoséDantas I only edit your question to remove the signature to help to your question to have "more quality"

Comment: Check the comment of @NicoHaase maybe it's better if you add to the question the structure

Comment: @Kalamarico thanks :)

Comment: @NicoHaase I´ve updated the question with the current structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days of searching I found the solution, if anyone will have this problem check this code:

```
var isAppleDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) != null;

var inputs = jQuery("input");
if ( isAppleDevice ){
        $(document).on('touchstart','body', function (evt) {
            var targetTouches = event.targetTouches;
            if ( !inputs.is(targetTouches)){
                inputs.context.activeElement.blur();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this problem only in Firefox for iOS strangely. The solution above worked, however.

Here's the VanillaJS solution:

```
function isiOS() { return navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone/i); }

if (isiOS()){
  var ins = [], _ins = document.querySelectorAll("input")
  for(var i = 0; i <ins.length; i++) ins.push(_ins[i])
  document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', event => {
    if(ins.filter(i => i.contains(event.target)).length == 0)
      document.activeElement.blur()
  });
}
```